# Browser Dom - How Much Data can it Hold

Tags: html, dom

Building an AJAX based site and to keep the speed as high as possible I plan to jquery hide() pages after a user navigates away from them.

This allows me to show() them again instantly if they select them again.

The site is a date site so the vast majority of pages that will be hidden with be members profiles & other std pages like mail, home, search etc.

Question - A std page would be around the same as this stackoverflow page (with respects to HTML/content etc). If I was to have 100 pages like this hidden in the DOM would it cause problems for browsers? What if it was 1000 pages or 5000 pages. I'm interested to know if browsers would struggle or crash if running a site with slowly growing large DOM.

Note: if its a problem I can timestamp pages and remove excess pages when I have over 100 in the DOM etc.

thoughts?

Comment: For a start you are going to experience problems when the punter first loads the page - all that parsing etc. Usually if a user does not get a response quite quickly they go elsewhere. So they will not experience the speed of subsequent pages.

Comment: when they first go to the site they would only see the first page... as each page is accessed it is then hidden - hide() - and can be shown again - show(). Thus the site should load as fast as must site would..

Comment: But the browser will receive the lot, have to parse it to create the DOM tree even if the page (i.e. part of the DOM tree) is hidden.

Comment: no... the brower will receive the first page. then if the user clicks another page it will hide the first page (that can be instantly shown again). if the user click a third page... the second page will be hidden... and so on... it slowly grows as the users clicks around the site...

Comment: But browsers already implement this - it is called a cache.

Comment: from my experience the entire page isn't cached... eg: images are but the HTML page is resent again. anyway this isn't my question... my question is about much data the DOM can hold before a browser has issues thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an impossible question to answer because

- Depends on the hardward the browser is running on that as a web site you have no control over
- Depends on the browser technology - something else the web site has no control over
- Depends on the available virtual memory - also the web site has no control over.

So in summary the web site has no control over the clients set up, so you have to make a reasonable assumption as to size of datastructures that it can hold in memory (be that real or virtual).

Comment: thankyou... wanted to see what people on stack had to say.. really appreciate all your input... thanks again!!